# Adding TurtleScreen to Canvas: 'Toplevel' object has no attribute 'call'

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to add a `TurtleScreen` to a tkinter `Canvas`. The code below shows the beginning of the function I am using it in, up to where it breaks:

```
def draw():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Your Drawing!")
    canvas = Canvas(top)
    canvas.pack()
    ts = turtle.TurtleScreen(canvas)  # this is the line causing an exception (line 36 in traceback)
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Blake/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "GUI.py", line 36, in draw
    ts = turtle.TurtleScreen(canvas)
  File "/Users/Blake/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 1001, in __init__
    rootwindow.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', '1')
AttributeError: 'Toplevel' object has no attribute 'call'
```

I can't figure out why is is trying to call a Toplevel object (I assume it is trying to call the `top` object). As far as I can tell from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.TurtleScreen) I found, I am doing this correctly. What's wrong here?

Comment: Looks like you've found a bug in the `turtle` module.  On OS X only, it's performing some code to make sure the turtle window properly appears in front of other windows - that contains an assumption that your Canvas is a child of the root window (the one you got from `Tk()`), NOT any other window (as you get from `Toplevel()`).

Comment: @jasonharper hmm, good to know, thank you. Is there any workaround? I've tried just using `Tk()` and it worked, but from what I've learned so far, you're not supposed to have more than 1 root window.

Comment: Edit `turtle.py`, and disable the block of code that starts with `if sys.platform == 'darwin':` - you may need to manually select the window to bring it to the front.  If you're not comfortable editing files in the standard library, or if you want to distribute your program to people who wouldn't want to make such an edit, you could temporarily set `sys.platform` to the empty string before creating your `TurtleScreen` (and set it back to its previous value afterwards).

Comment: @jasonharper the temporary change worked perfectly. Thank you!