# Error with RawTurtle in canvas and tkinter window: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, tkinter, python-turtle

When trying to use a raw turtle using the turtle library in a canvas within a tkinter window I am unable to set position, get position, or move the rawturtle object.

```
class PatientWindow():
    def __init__(self):

        top = customtkinter.CTkToplevel()
        top.geometry("600x850")
        top.title("Exoskeleton Patient View")
        self.frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(top)

        im = Image.open("images/please-wait2.png")
        resized = im.resize((600, 600), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        ph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)

        self.label = Label(self.frame, image=ph, width=600, height=600)
        self.label.image = ph  # need to keep the reference of your image to avoid garbage collection
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        w = 600
        h = 250

        self.frame_bottom = customtkinter.CTkFrame(top)
        self.canvas = customtkinter.CTkCanvas(self.frame_bottom, width=w, height=h, bg='gray')
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

        x = w // 2
        y = h // 2
        cursor = self.canvas.create_oval(x, y, x+10, y+10, fill='red')

        # left_wall = self.canvas.create_rectangle(125, 90, 100, 165, fill='pink')

        self.frame_bottom.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.screen = turtle.TurtleScreen(self.canvas)
        self.screen.bgcolor("cyan")
        self.wall = turtle.RawTurtle(self.canvas, shape='turtle')
        self.wall.shapesize(stretch_len=2, stretch_wid=2)
        self.wall.color("green")
        self.wall.setposition((100, 100))
```

Below is the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\benja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\benja\ALL CODING\CapstoneGUI\venv\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 377, in clicked
    self.command()
  File "C:\Users\benja\ALL CODING\CapstoneGUI\main.py", line 74, in open
    self.patientWindow = PatientWindow()
  File "C:\Users\benja\ALL CODING\CapstoneGUI\main.py", line 150, in __init__
    self.wall.setposition((100, 100))
  File "C:\Users\benja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 1774, in goto
    self._goto(Vec2D(*x))
  File "C:\Users\benja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 3159, in _goto
    screen._pointlist(self.currentLineItem),
  File "C:\Users\benja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 754, in _pointlist
    pl = [(cl[i], -cl[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(cl), 2)]
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

The PatientWindow is a toplevel window, so maybe it could be an issue with the rawturtle being in a screen, in a canvas, in a frame, in a window class that is inside another window class?

Comment: The CustomTkinter implementation of Canvas is broken - specifically, its `.coords()` method is only usable for *setting* the coordinates of a drawing item, it cannot retrieve the existing coordinates of an item like a plain Tkinter Canvas can.  And this ability is being relied on by the `turtle` module...

Comment: Instead of calling `turtle.RawTurtle(self.canvas, shape='turtle')` you probably want `turtle.RawTurtle(self.screen, shape='turtle')` otherwise you'll have conflicts/problems.  The failure message is coming from Turtle's UNDO logic which confirms @jasonharper's explanation.

Comment: Turtle doesn't play nice when embedded in a generic tkinter `Toplevel()` window which @jasonharper [explains here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59340651/5771269) along with a workaround.

Comment: A test might be to turn off Turtle's UNDO functionality via `turtle.setundobuffer(None)` but my guess is you'll run up against the CustomTkinter Canvas limitations some other way.

Comment: @jasonharper CustomTkinter seems to be the issue, thanks for the info!